# Gather statistics for a huge oracle table - worry of collapsing the server

Tags: oracle, table-statistics

I'm trying to improve the execution time of a view of an Oracle database, which takes ages to load, and it involves a table which has 15,352,595 records. I'm considering to gather statistics on it coz I suspect the poor performance is due to stale stats.

However, I'm worried that this will burden the server a lot and I'm not very confident that its harddisks (or whatever hardware components) can withstand heavy workloads without breaking.

Is that a real thing that should be worried?

Comment: 15 million rows isn't very large. If you're worried about impacting performance for your end users, why not run it during the night/weekend? But I guess you have bigger fish to fry - if your server is as fragile as you suggest, you should first and foremost ensure that you have a working backup strategy before starting to optimize performance.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I think your comment is the correct answer to this question

Comment: its pathetic, but no one on my side has the expertise to backup an Oracle in the right way

Comment: what I want is to see if the risk is low enough to do the stats, like if 15mil of rows is actually too little to actually be a risk of bringing down the harddisks, or if that the stat-ing is actually quite safe and no need to worry about it, then I may go ahead

Comment: Normally, I'd just go ahead and compute the statistics. But if you want to be sure, I'd suggest you create a smaller test table (say 10% of your real table) and compute the statistics with `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(, ... degree => 1);` This will ensure Oracle doesn't use parallel queries for the analysis. If your database can handle this, I'd go ahead and gather the stats for your production table.

Answer (score 1):

You can gather statistics with low value of estimate percentage.